# Creating a dataset based on a different dataset

Tags: reporting-services

I've been looking and thus far haven't been able to figure out if this is possible.

Say I have a datasource, SOURCE1.  I create a dataset from it, SET1.  Now, I'd like to be able to make another Dataset that uses SET1 as the data source.  Is there any way I can do this?  I'd like to be able to run a series of queries that work together to build a final result which would be reported.

ie:
SET1 = SELECT * FROM SOURCE1 WHERE ...

SET2 = SELECT * FROM SET1 WHERE ...

Otherwise, would the only option be to just keep embedding the queries? I'd rather avoid this if possible, because it would become very unreadable since I have to run at least a dozen queries that all build off of each other.

SET 2 = SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM SET 1 WHERE ...) WHERE ...

Comment: You say you want to build a series of queries that are used to get a final result. If you only need one result why do you think you have to create multiple datasets? Are you trying to create a series of shared datasets that you can use across multiple reports? Give us a bit more info and there might be a workaround or best practice as using a dataset in another dataser is not really possible in the way you are (probably) thinking

Comment: @AlanSchofield Basically, I have a series of queries in Access that I want to switch over to being created through queries in SSRS. The main reason I want to create multiple datasets is because I'm not sure if it is possible to generate the goal dataset by just using one query,  It takes a series of about 15 queries to get to the final end result, and it seems like it would be easier to create the dataset in steps as opposed to trying to incorporate all 15 queries into one massive query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess (not knowing your queries) that you would be able to write it as a single query. The lazy approach would just be to run each query in a batch outputting each result to a series of temp tables then join the temp tables for your final output. If might not be efficient but it would work. The best solution would, almost certainly, be to rewrite it from scratch though as Access SQL is not as powerful or flexible as T-SQL.

So you would need something like..

```
SELECT * INTO #t1 FROM myTable WHERE blah blah...
SELECT * INTO #t2 FROM myOtherTable WHERE blah blah...
SELECT * 
    FROM #t1 a
    JOIN #t2 b on a.myField = b.myField
```

You can put this query directly into your dataset query. It will dump the results of each query into temp table (#t1, #t2 etc) and then the final statement would join them all.

If you plan to use the individual queries in several places, then you might also consider creating a view for each query if this is possible then just join the views in your SSRS dataset query to get your final results.

In SSMS create the views with something like

```
CREATE VIEW AccessQuery1 AS
SELECT * FROM myTable where blah blah...

CREATE VIEW AccessQuery2 AS
SELECT * FROM myOtherTable where blah blah...
```

Then in SSRS your dataset query would just be something like

```
SELECT * 
    FROM AccessQuery1 a
    JOIN AccessQuery2  b on a.myField = b.myField
```

Hope that helps...